# How do I implement a function that stops users from uploading files when I set it to true

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a flutter app that allows users to upload text documents to firebase. Is there a way to disable the upload button for all users; for example setting a `bool canUpload = true;` paramter to the upload button and set it to false when no user is supposed to upload? I was going to try this but how would I set the button to listen for change in the `canUpload` value?

Comment: Do you need code or an idea of how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ValueNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) and [ValueListenableBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html)

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ValueNotifier<bool> canUpload = ValueNotifier<bool>(true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                canUpload.value = !canUpload.value;
              },
              child: Text("data"),
            ),
          ),
          ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: canUpload,
            builder: (BuildContext context, bool value, Widget? child) {
              return ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: value ? () => print("Upload") : () => print("No need to upload"),
                child: Text('Upload'),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```